# How to pass unbalanced arguments to mapply

Tags: r, mapply

Hi I have the following code working.

It calculates the percentage difference between two periods. For the first period, the function returns NA as there is no change.

I want to replace the following code with mapply and pass two arguments to fn.pc.

```
ts <- c(12, 14, 15, 17, 12, 8, 13, 16, 20)
fn.pc <- function(i) {
if (i == 1) NA else (ts[i] - ts[i-1]) / ts[i-1] 
}
sapply(seq_along(tsVector), fn.pc)
```

For example, the function signature above would be replaced with:

```
fn.pc <- function(i, ts) {...
```

And then this function would be called by mapply using something like the following:

```
mapply(fn.pc, seq_along(ts.vector), ts.vector)
```

But I cannot get this idea to work.  I think this is because the lengths of the two arguments are different.

I there any way I can this to work.  Hope this is clear. A bit tricky to explain.

Comment: why do you want to achieve? you do not need mapply there ... sapply is enough.

Comment: sapply() sure does work with the example posted above.  But what about when I have many different time series.  ts1 <- (1,4,5) ; ts2 <- (42, 44, 50)  I would like to use the same function definition many different input arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a list of vector `lst`. You can proceed like this:

```
lapply(lst, function(x) sapply(seq_along(x), function(u) diff(x,u)))
```

Simply use `diff` for the difference:

```
x = c(12,34,23,11,34,45,12,11)

> diff(x,2)
[1]  11 -23  11  34 -22 -34
> diff(x,3)
[1]  -1   0  22   1 -23
> diff(x,4)
[1]  22  11 -11   0
> diff(x,5)
[1]  33 -22 -12
```

Comment: Thats nice. Thanks!  You right I probably could this...but I want to make this concept work with mapply() It will be useful for more complex things than just calculating percentagies.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will review. Late here in NZ.